# How to check if a string is contained in a substring in Crystal Lang?

Tags: crystal-lang

I don't see a `String#contains` method or a `String#search` method in the Crystal API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`String#includes?`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/String.html#includes%3F%28search%3AChar%7CString%29-instance-method) which checks if the search exists in the string and returns a bool or [`String#index`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.24.2/String.html#index%28search%3AString%2Coffset%3D0%29-instance-method) which returns the index of the search if it exists.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't check that. Thank you

Comment: No problem! I also highly recommend using [Crystal docs on DevDocs](https://devdocs.io/crystal) as their search is superior than the search available on the official documentation.

Comment: @Svenskunganka the search is much improved in `master`, check it out: https://crystal-lang.org/api/master/